# Не устанавливается соединение с ошибкой - Could not create connection to database server

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Мне не помогли ответы, которые я нашел в интернете.
Что мы имеем:

1. Есть несколько вариаций кода
2. Есть несколько версий JDBC, которые я использовал
3. Есть база данных к которой без проблем подключаемся в командной строке
4. Отключены все антивирусы, брандмауэры и vpn, которые могут помешать соединени.
5. В базе данных чарсет задан как UTF8 general ci
6. JDBC зависимость указываю через Maven

Вот основной код:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MySQLConnect {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MySQLConnect m = new MySQLConnect();
        m.testDatabase();
    }
    private void testDatabase() {
        try {
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/telegramphotoid?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
            String login = "root";
            String password = "root";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
            try {
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM photoid");
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String str = rs.getString("id") + ":" + rs.getString(2);
                    System.out.println("fileId:" + str);
                }
                rs.close();
                stmt.close();
            } finally {
                con.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Код Maven

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>testbd</groupId>
    <artifactId>bdtest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>7</source>
                    <target>7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

И вывод ошибки:

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:108)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:87)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:71)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:932)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:857)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:444)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:230)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:226)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at MySQLConnect.testDatabase(MySQLConnect.java:18)
    at MySQLConnect.main(MySQLConnect.java:11)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'RTZ 2 (çèìà)' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:59)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:83)
    at com.mysql.cj.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:128)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.configureTimezone(NativeProtocol.java:2201)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.initServerSession(NativeProtocol.java:2225)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:1391)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:895)
    ... 8 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Код номер 2:

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class MySQLDriver {
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
    private static final String USERNAME = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "root";
    public void dbtest() {

        System.out.println("------- Проверка подключения к MySQL -------");

        Connection connection = null;
        MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
        dataSource.setUser(USERNAME);
        dataSource.setPassword(PASSWORD);
        dataSource.setServerName(URL);

        if(null != connection) {
            System.out.println("------- Подключение установлено -------");
        } else {
            System.out.println("------- Подключение НЕ установлено -------");
        }


        try {
            Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM telegramphotoid");
            System.out.println("code...");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Не удалось установить соединение!");
            return;
        }
```

Maven кода номер 2:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.36</version>
        </dependency>
```

И ее вывод:

```
------- Проверка подключения к MySQL -------
------- Подключение НЕ установлено -------
Не удалось установить соединение!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

У меня уже сложилось впечатление, что ошибка в настройке моей локальной сети или я просто упустил какую-то элементарную вещь и не вижу ее замыленным взглядом.

Comment: Пробовали перевести текст ошибки "The server time zone value 'RTZ 2 (çèìà)' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support."?

Comment: Искренне благодарю, глаза замыленны, смотрю и не вижу. Добавил serverTimezone=UTC в String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/telegramphotoid?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC" и все заработало. Да будут долгими и чудесными твои годы, во имя всех возможных людей и Богов